# Adjust font size in multi-head setup with different resolutions

Tags: window-manager, fonts, resolution, window-management, multi-monitor

I have a multi monitor setting with the main screen resolution 3840x2160 and two additional screens running on 1920x1080.
When I drag for example a firefox window between the screens, Windows seems to somehow automagically adjust font and image sizes, so the web page is always readable.

In linux however, moving between resolutions makes the text either extremely small (on the main screen) or too large (on the additional screens).
Is there a way to get windows-like behaviour in this matter?

I'm currently using KDE, but I'd switch to a different window manager if that is necessary to solve the problem.